# How to get the content of mf.dll

Tags: .net, dll, com, visual-studio-2012, ms-media-foundation

I think this is a simple question, but still I am too inexperienced to answer it myself.
I searched a way to use Windows Mediafoundation inside of .NET i.e. C# and found some kind of wrapper, what will do exactly what I need.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mf/archive/2010/02/18/mfmanagedencode.aspx and
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mfblog

While trying to analyze the wrapper I asked myself, how would I know of all these functions, types and *.dll files which are part of the WMF?! I found dumpbin.exe to get all the functions and properties, but still there is no information about the arguments to call the function and nothing about the different types and in which *.dll file the types are declared. Where do I get the Guid?

Comment: Consult the documentation for MF. For example, the ASF Payload Extension GUIDs are documented on a page sneakily named "[ASF Payload Extension GUIDs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms703998(v=vs.85).aspx)".

Comment: Is anything wrong with the front door for MF documentation? [Microsoft Media Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Okay, now I know how to get the dll file that contains a specific function, thanks for that. But I am still stucked at finding the GUID (for COMImport) for i.e.: `IMFTranscodeProfile` which should be a COMInterface as far as I know. Where can I find those interfaces? I read something about I could simply add the Interface to VS2012 as a reference, but still I can not find it inside my available COM-Typelibraries ... maybe I just misunderstand the concept?!

Comment: `IMFTranscodeProfile`'s GUID is in Windows SDK `Include\Mfidl.*` files, this is what native code applications reference to make the definitions available.